# Are Haar measures complete?

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

If $G$ is a locally compact group and $\mu$ is a left Haar measure for $G$, then is the measure space $(G,B(G),\mu)$ complete (where $B(G)$ is the set of Borel subsets of $G$)?

Or do we have to take their completion before we can use something like Fubini's Theorem which only applies to complete measure spaces?

Comment: The Borel sigma algebra is not complete. I'm writing this as a comment since I might be missing something but modifying [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure)'s argument with $G = [0,1]/\sim = S^1$ seems to work.

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot completeness is a property of $B(G)$ even though it is given to $\mu$.

So in practice do we normally just take $B_{0}$ to be the completion of $B(G)$ and identify $\mu$ with its natural extension $\mu_{0}$ to all of $B_{0}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the Haar measure on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ complete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219267/is-the-haar-measure-on-mathbbq-p-complete)